# Dialogflow Agent Conversation

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is there a way to get the Dialogflow agent's conversation history programmatically?

I made a chatbot using Dialogflow. Now I need to get the conversation history of my agent programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That feature (an important one) is **not available** yet.

Since there is not an API call to retrieve a history of conversation So, the only way I know how is to

Go to the Training tab and see the conversations that way, although it only gives the reply in the form of the intent, and not what the bot actually replied.

But if you want to access all conversations history then don't go for one-click integration make your own login system with Outh2 and integrate using [Detect Intent Api](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#detect_intent_and_agent_apis) and store your conversations by logs.

Then you can get conversation history programmatically.

> You need to log all the requests by writing your own code if you want
>   to get the history.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what history u meant to fetch.
You can easily integrate your agent with google chatbase and you can get the conversation history pretty simple.
You don't need to write any programs and all.
Chatbase Automatically keeps track of history and user messages.
But it can only store history of past 30 days. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the NodeJS library, aling with Dialogflow, one option for you would be to save your conversation inside the user object. That way the data /conversation can be accessed by the user in future sessions.

Here's how I'll go about implementing this:
`function saveConv(conv){
   Conv.user.storage.convToSave = 'conversation_object'.
}`

To access it I'll do:
`function getSavedConv(conv){
  var savedConv = conv.user.storage.convToSave.
}`

Please let me know if this amswered your question.